# JBoss 7.1.1. bound to 2 ip addresses

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, hornetq

I have a server PC with 2 ethernet card, so it has two IP addresses. A JBoss 7.1.1 is running on the server PC. 
I bound the JBoss to 0.0.0.0, because the JBoss has to receive jms messages from the first IP address, but the user interface communicates with it through the second IP address.

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0"
```

The jms messaging didn't work (couldn't find the queue) unless i set the jboss bind address to the first IP

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.89.253"
```

But at this time the user can't communicate with the server. How can i configure the JBoss to make the jms work and at the same time the user can reach the server through the second ip with the user interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jBoss community gave me the answer. I have to define a new interface

```
<interface name="my-interface">
        <inet-address value="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"/>
</interface>
```

And the messaging uses this interface:

```
<socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445" interface="my-interface" />
```

The jboss.bind.address remains 0.0.0.0

```
-Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0
```

source:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/266416

Answer (score 0):

The first solution would be to stick with the specific binding

```
-Djboss.bind.address=192.168.89.253
```

and change public interface in a standalone.xml file:

```
<interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
</interface>
```

You could achieve that by introducing a new system property e.g.: jboss.bind.address.public or by writing IP address directly in the XML file.

The second solution would be to change a bind address for jgroups:

```
-b 0.0.0.0 -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.0.0.1
```

It may help when using a ha profile. JGroups uses jboss binding address (-b) as a default interface, but doesn't work well with 0.0.0.0 binding.